# Routing tables and ip forwarding between two machines

Tags: linux, networking, forwarding, routing

Hi my current network is like that

```
[Raspberry]--eth0--------p3p1-[Laptop]-wlp3s0------[Router]-------INTERNET
eth0 = 10.10.10.1
p3p1 = 10.10.10.2
wlp3s0 = 192.168.2.11
Router = 192.168.2.1
```

I would like to give access to the Internet to Raspberry.
I turned on port forwarding on Laptop

```
[kamil@laura ~]$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
1
```

I checked route table on Raspberry

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.10.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I set up route on my Laptop:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         router          0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlp3s0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 p3p1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlp3s0
```

But my Raspberry cant ping router ip address, it waits all the time.
What am I missing, please help!

IPTables are turned off on both machines.

Comment: you can't use the same IP for both eth0 and p3p1. try setting one of them to `10.10.10.3`. then you will need to use some software to bridge your connection, or proxy traffic from the 10.10.10.0/24 network. that way all traffic from 10.10.10.0 appears to the router to come from the laptop, and replies will be sent to it. the proxy application will take responsibility for sending the responses to the interior net.

Comment: Yes I made copy and paste error with those ip addresses, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Change the IP address on the p3p1 interface of your laptop to 10.10.10.1.
2. Enable IP forwarding (not port forwarding) on your laptop.  If it's Linux, use: 
   sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
3. Add a route to your router:  10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 next-hop: 192.168.2.11

You may have to mess with NAT on the router, to NAT for 10.x.x.x addresses.  That would depend on the brand of router.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons why this won't work. Here are two:

1. The router has no idea that it's supposed to NAT for machines with 10.x addresses. It believes its clients have 192.168.x addresses.
2. The router has no idea that packets (even locally generated ones) bound for 10.10.10.2 should be sent to the laptop. Yet there is no other IP address it can use as a destination to get packets to the pi. Thus the router *cannot* reach the pi. At all. By any means. Period.

You need to start out by designing the way this will all work and then implement that. It won't just happen by itself. Implementing NAT on the laptop would probably be the easiest way.

Comment: Does it mean that even such basic protocol as ping will not work if NAT is not in place?

Comment: @Kamil No. Pinging the router would work if the router had some idea how to reach the pi. But the router has no way to do that with your setup -- even it formed a packet with destination address `10.10.10.2`, why would it send it to the laptop?